# Escape newline character in heredoc on solaris

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, heredoc

I am using bash and this works on Linux:

```
read -r -d '' VAR<<-EOF
  Hello\nWorld
EOF

echo $VAR > trail
```

i.e the contents of the file on Linux is

```
Hello\nWorld
```

When i run on Solaris
trial file has

```
Hello
World
```

The newline(\n) is being replaced with a newline. How can i avoid it?

Is it a problem with heredoc or the echo command?

**[UPDATE]**

Based on the explanation provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521510/escape-newline-character-in-heredoc-on-solaris/23522416?noredirect=1#23522416):

```
echo -E $VAR > trail
```

worked fine on Solaris.

Comment: Are you using `bash` or `ksh` on Solaris?

Comment: Does `echo 'Hello\nworld'` contain a newline in the middle on Solaris? It should be a Bash builtin regardless of platform, but if your Bash is very old...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [@that other guy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23521707/45375):

**Even when it *is* `bash` executing your script, there are several ways in which the observed behavior - `echo` by default interpreting escape sequences such as `\n` - can come about**:

- `shopt -s xpg_echo` could be in effect, which makes the `echo` builtin interpret `\` escape sequences by default.
- `enable -n echo` could be in effect, which disables the `echo` *builtin* and runs the *external executable* by default - and that executable's behavior is *platform-dependent*.

These options are normally NOT inherited when you run a script, but there are still **ways in which they could take effect**:

- If your interactive initialization files (e.g., `~/.bashrc`) contain commands such as the above and you **`source`** (`.`) your script from an interactive shell.
- When not sourcing your script: If your environment contains a **`BASH_ENV`** variable that points to a script, that script is *sourced* before your script runs; thus, if that script contains commands such as the above, they will affect your script.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with `echo`. Behavior is defined [in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), where interpretting `\n` is part of XSI but not basic POSIX itself.

You can avoid this on all platforms using `printf` (which is good practice anyways):

```
printf "%s\n" "$VAR"
```

This is not a problem for `bash` by the way. If you had used `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the shebang (and also not run the script with `sh script`), behavior would have been consistent.

If you use `#!/bin/sh`, you'll get whichever shell the system uses as a default, with varying behaviors like this.